# Valid Sudoku please can anyone correct this code Does this can be done by recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Can anybody tell me where it went wrong?

it seems correct but output is showing false can anyone recorrect or point out the mistake i made

```
type here



class Solution:
    def isValidSudoku(self, board: List[List[str]]) -> bool:
        col=0

        def check(row,col):
            duprow = row
            dupcol = col

            if board[row][col] == ".":
                return True

            row=duprow
            col1 = dupcol+1
            while col1<len(board):
                if board[row][col] == board[row][col1]:
                    return False
                col1+=1
            row=duprow
            col1 = dupcol-1
            while col1>len(board):
                if board[row][col] == board[row][col1]:
                    return False
                col1-=1


            row=duprow
            row1 = duprow+1
            col = dupcol

            while row1<len(board):
                if board[row][col] == board[row1][col]:
                    return False
                row1+=1
            
            row = duprow
            row1 = duprow-1
            col = dupcol

            while row1>0:
                if board[row][col] == board[row1][col]:
                    return False
                row-=1

            st = set()
            row = duprow -(duprow%3)
            col = dupcol -(dupcol%3)
            for i in range(0,3):
                for j in range(0,3):
                    curr = board[row+i][col+j]
                    if curr in st:
                        return False
                    if curr !=".":
                        st.add(curr)
            return True

        def solve(col):
            if col>=len(board):
                return

            for row in range(len(board)):
                if not check(row,col):
                    return False
                else:
                    solve(col+1)
            
            return True
        
        return solve(col)
```

Determine if a 9 x 9 Sudoku board is valid. Only the filled cells need to be validated according
[image: its the output]
the following rules:

Each row must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.
Each column must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.
Each of the nine 3 x 3 sub-boxes of the grid must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.
Note:

A Sudoku board (partially filled) could be valid but is not necessarily solvable.
Only the filled cells need to be validated according to the mentioned rules.

[image: input/output image]

Comment: Solving this does not require recursion.

Comment: *"please can anyone correct this code"*: did any of the answers below help to correct your code? Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

There are several bugs in your code:

- In `check`, the second loop has a condition that will never be true: `while col1>len(board)`. It is not breaking the algorithm because this loop is not necessary. It intends to find the same value at the *left* in the same row, but it is enough to only look at the right (what the first loop does).
- In `check`, the fourth loop is not visiting the row at index 0: `while row1>=1`. Again, this is not breaking the algorithm because this loop is not necessary for similar reasons as in the first bullet point.
- However, the forth loop is decrementing `row` instead of `row1`, and so execution may get stuck in an infinite loop.
- In `solve` you should return `True` when `col>=len(board)`, as that means you have checked all columns and there was no problem. By just doing `return`, the caller will understand that to mean it was *not* OK.
- `else: solve(col+1)` is problematic, because it is done inside the loop over the rows, that means `solve` is called many times for the same column. There is no reason to check the same column multiple times, and this has a catastrophic impact on the efficiency of your code. Unless a sudoku violation is found this means that all possible paths are traversed (with steps going right or down) from the top-left corner of the grid to the bottom-right corner of the grid. There are more than 48,000 such paths! Instead `solve(col+1)` should be called *after* the loop over the rows.
- When calling `solve(col+1)` your code ignores the value returned by it, making the call useless. You'll want to know whether the result was positive or negative. So use `return solve(col+1)`.

With those fixes (if applied well), your code will run.

### More remarks

This is however not very efficient code. As already remarked in the first few bullet points above, there is no need to scan a row or column in backwards direction.  But more than that, it should not be necessary to scan a row or column **for each** value that is in that row or column. One scan is enough: count the number of occurrences for each value as you iterate the row/column and verify that no number has an occurrence of more than 1.

There is no need for recursion here. Just like you didn't use recursion to traverse a row, so it is not necessary to traverse the columns.

Try to avoid repetition of similar code. You could concentrate on checking whether a series of 9 cells is valid or not, independent on whether it is a row, a column, or a 3x3 square. Then create a function to collect the cells of a given column, and another one to collect the cells of a 3x3 square. And then you have everything to solve the problem in a concise and elegant way.

### Spoiler solution

> `class Solution:
>      def isValidSudoku(self, board: List[List[str]]) -> bool:
>          def column(i):
>              return [row[i] for row in board]
>
>          def square(i):
>              row = i - i % 3
>              col = (i % 3) * 3
>              return [cell for row in board[row:row+3] for cell in row[col:col+3]]
>
>          def isValidLine(line):
>              values = [cell for cell in line if cell != "."]  # exclude empty cells
>              return len(values) == len(set(values))  # values are unique
>
>          return all(
>              isValidLine(line)
>              for i in range(9)
>              for line in (board[i], column(i), square(i))
>          )`

Answer (score 0):

A set is usually the simplest way to check for duplicates. There are 27 groups on a sudoku board (9 columns, 9 rows and 9 blocks).  For the board to be valid, there must be no duplicates in any of these groups.

You can test for this using a single set by adding (groupID,PlacedNumber) pairs to the set.  Give different identifiers to the 27 groups.  For example: 0-8 for the block groups, 9-17 for the row groups and 18-26 for the column groups.  This way, the group numbers can easily be computed from the row and column index.  Each position is part of exactly 3 groups and could cause duplication in any of them.

For example:

```
def isValid(board):
    seen = set()
    for r,row in enumerate(board):
        for c,number in enumerate(row):
            if number == ".": continue
            for groupID in (r//3*3+c//3,r+9,c+18):
                if (groupID, number) in seen: 
                    return False
                seen.add((groupID, number))
    return True
```